# What is the difference between gcnew and ref new

Tags: c++-cli

I just have stumbled upon `ref new` [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/windows/tracking-reference-operator-cpp-component-extensions?view=vs-2017) and am wondering whether there is a difference to `gcnew`.

The code example [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/windows/tracking-reference-operator-cpp-component-extensions?view=vs-2017) shows how a handle to an object on the managed heap is being created using ref new:

```
Foo^ spFoo = ref new Foo();
```

and using gcnew [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/dotnet/how-to-unbox?view=vs-2017)

```
 int ^ i = gcnew int(13);
```

So are they conceptually equivalent?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In case you are simply confused by the layout of the documentation:

C++/CLI is for the Common Language Runtime (CLR).

C++/CX is for the Windows Runtime (WinRT).

They are similar enough to be documented together but they are not the same.

That's why they have three headings in the documentation that you linked:

- All Platforms
- Windows Runtime
- Common Language Runtime

For C++/CLI, `gcnew` is what you use. Unless you are using C++/CX, the "Windows Runtime" sections don't apply.

Comment: This answer would benefit from actually tying it back to `ref new` and `gcnew`.  Right now the coder such as OP who hasn't used both C++/CLI and C++/CX is not going to understand that you actually did answer the question.

Comment: Thanks @BenVoigt. I provided more context for the intent of my answer.  It is meant only to address the surface issue of understanding that there are two different runtimes.

Comment: Thanks @TomBlodget. Additionaly to your answer I have tested whether ref new does work on C++/CLI and, as you might expect, it does not: `(C2065) ref: undeclared identifier. (C2143) syntax error: missing ; before new`